# how to arrange below table in assending order in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to arrange the output table in ascending order `ORDER BY ASC` **doesn't** work in showing table but works with table elements
my code is as follows:

```
<?php  
 $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM st_db_1");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
     $result_tb = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $row[0] LIMIT 1");
     $row_tb=mysql_fetch_array($result_tb);

     //checking for availbility of result_tb
     if (!$result_tb) {
              echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
              echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
              exit;
     }
     echo "<a href=exa.php?id=$row_tb[id]>{$row[0]}<br/><a/>" ;
 }
 mysql_free_result($result);
 mysql_free_result($result_tb);
?>
```

Comment: Don't you need `"SELECT id FROM {$row[0]} LIMIT 1"`

Comment: Yup, references to arrays must be wrapped around curly braces inside quoted strings. That's an issue. Not sure if that's the actual issue that ravi is originally having, but it's still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  TABLE_NAME
from    information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
order by TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

Orders the table_names.

See *(at the bottom of the page)*: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14473

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_tb = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $row[0] LIMIT 1 s ORDER BY id ASC");
```

you have to use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: @ravi you have to replace name with the field you want the arrangement to happen, like `id` or whatever. `name` was just an example. read the link i've posted

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that

```
SHOW TABLES FROM st_db_1 ORDER BY x ASC
```

doesn't work, it's because there is no such syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html). You can, however, sort the result via PHP and then SELECT each table:

```
<?php  
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM st_db_1");
$tableArr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tableArr[] = $row;
}

usort($tableArr, function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0] == $b[0])
        return 0;
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

foreach($tableArr as $row) {
    $result_tb = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $row[0] LIMIT 1");
    $row_tb = mysql_fetch_array($result_tb);

    //checking for availbility of result_tb
    if (!$result_tb) {
        echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    echo "<a href=exa.php?id=$row_tb[id]>{$row[0]}<br/><a/>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_free_result($result_tb);
```